# How to provide a countType when using mathcomp?

Tags: coq, coq-mathcomp

The following snippet can't pass type checking.

```
From mathcomp Require Import choice.
Definition exfn (A:countType) := false.
(* Fail *) Check exfn nat.
```

Failed with message: The term "nat" has type "Set" while it is expected to have type "countType".

How to instantiate **A** with **nat** properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why the <s>type-classes</s> canonical structure mechanism can't figure this out on its own. However, there are two ways of making it explicit: `nat_countType`, as mentioned by Pierre, and `[countType of nat]`. <s>The latter is a notation defined outside `choice`, I'm not sure where, but importing `all_ssreflect` suffices to obtain it.</s> For the latter, you need to import at least `ssreflect`.

Note that `[fooType of X]` works for other types as well, such as `eqType`, `choiceType`, etc. And it works even when `X` is not a "base" type. For example, `[countType of nat * nat]` works, whereas `"nat*nat"_countType` is not a thing.

Comment: The notation actually is defined in `choice`, you just need to import `ssreflect` for it to work. It's usually a good idea to add `From Coq Require Import ssreflect ssrbool ssrfun` by default (if you're not importing `all_ssreflect`), as not doing so will typically result in cryptic errors.

Comment: Also, technically the mechanism used here is canonical structures, not typeclasses.

Answer (score 1):

I see there is a `nat_countType` in `mathcomp.ssreflect.choice`:

```
From mathcomp Require Import choice.
Definition exfn (A:countType) := false.
Check exfn nat_countType.

Variable (x : nat_countType).

Definition y : nat := x + 42.
```

Comment: But supposedly the type-classes mechanism should be able to pick it up automatically?